# How to convert int array to base64 string in Java?

Tags: java, base64, unsigned

How do I convert this array:

```
int[] ints = { 233, 154, 24, 196, 40, 203, 56, 213, 242, 96, 133, 54, 120, 146, 46, 3 };
```

To this string?

```
String base64Encoded = "6ZoYxCjLONXyYIU2eJIuAw==";
```

*Usage:*

```
String base64Encoded  = ConvertToBase64(int[] ints);
```

*(I'm asking this questions because `byte` in Java is signed, but `byte` in C# is unsigned)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem can be broken down into 2 simple steps: 1. Convert the int array to a byte array. 2. Encode the byte array to base4.

Here's one way to do that:

```
public static String convertToBase64(int[] ints) {
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(ints.length);
    IntStream.of(ints).forEach(i -> buf.put((byte)i));
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(buf.array());
}
```

A more old school approach:

```
public static String convertToBase64(int[] ints) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[ints.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = (byte)ints[i];
    }
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
}
```

[View running code on Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Yfwcrv)

Comment: Please Provide Explanation To Your Answer!

Comment: @shmosel: won't the `int` get converted to a signed `byte` in your examples?  That would generate a different `string`.  Please see my requirements.

Comment: @JohnB You haven't posted any requirement, just a sample input and output, which my solution achieves.

Comment: @shmosel: your code converted my `int` array to a signed `byte` array. *(see the comment I added above)*  My `int` array has unsigned values.  Your code will render a different base64 `string` than what I specified in my question.  Did you test this code?

Comment: @JohnB There's nothing wrong with signed bytes; bytes are always signed in Java. Whether the narrowing conversion from `int` to `byte` is the correct interpretation of your data depends on what your data represents. Since you have yet to specify that, I took a guess and verified the result by testing. I guess it's my turn to ask: did you test this code?

Comment: @shmosel: my apologies.  I was having trouble running your code in Android Studio, but your Ideone.com demo proves it works.  Thanks.