# In Java - Convert ArrayList<Integer> to Byte Array then convert Byte Array to BLOB

Tags: java, arrays

I have climate data such as moisture, pressure, temp etc ... that are daily values, and need to do calculations over a month, and many different months.
This leads to data that is either DOUBLE or INTEGER data that are put into Arraylists.

I want to be able to convert this ArrayList to a Byte Array, then compress this
to a Binary BLOB, and store in a database in a BLOB field.
I knew someone before that did this in python was able to convert Array to ByteArray and then
put into database BLOB field.

I have seen some links here, but it is not exactly the same.
It is really confusing the different ways to do this.
For example here from this link, they encode to base64.
[How to convert int array to base64 string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059116/how-to-convert-int-array-to-base64-string-in-java)

Hope someone can provide guidance into this area.

P.

Comment: An int is 4 bytes. So create a byte array 4x the size of the list, then for each int, put the various bytes of the int (use bitshift operators).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ByteBuffer` to convert a collection of integers to a byte array.

```java
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Collection;

public class Foo {

    public static byte[] toByteArray(Collection<Integer> ints) {
        // an integer in Java is a 32-bit number (i.e., 4 bytes)
        int capacity = Math.multiplyExact(ints.size(), 4);
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(capacity);
        ints.forEach(buffer::putInt);
        return buffer.array();
    }
}
```

<sup>**Note:** The above `ByteBuffer` will be using the `BIG_ENDIAN` byte order. You can change that to `LITTLE_ENDIAN` if you need to.</sup>

Then, assuming you're using JDBC directly, you just need to make use of:

- [`Connection#createBlob()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#createBlob())
- [`Blob#setBytes(long,byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Blob.html#setBytes(long,byte%5B%5D))
- [`PreparedStatement#setBlob(int,Blob)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBlob(int,java.sql.Blob))

Note there's also the [`PreparedStatement#setBlob(int,InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBlob(int,java.io.InputStream)) method. Meaning you could create an `InputStream` that reads the bytes from your integers. This may have significant memory-use improvements depending on how large your integer collection is (and the JDBC driver implementation), as you don't have to allocate a byte buffer/array.

```java
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class IntegerInputStream extends InputStream {

    private final Iterator<Integer> ints;

    private int currentInt;
    private int byteIndex = -1;

    public IntegerInputStream(Iterable<Integer> ints) {
        this.ints = ints.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int read() {
        if (byteIndex == -1) {
            if (ints.hasNext()) {
                currentInt = ints.next();
                byteIndex = 3;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        int next = (currentInt >> 8 * byteIndex) & 0xFF;
        byteIndex--;
        return next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard java serizlizations works fine in this case:

```java
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    List<Integer> numbers = IntStream.range(0, 100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    byte[] buf = serialize(numbers);
    List<Integer> res = deserialize(buf);
}

public static byte[] serialize(List<Integer> numbers) throws IOException {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out)) {
        oos.writeObject(numbers);
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}

public static List<Integer> deserialize(byte[] buf) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bais)) {
        return (List<Integer>) in.readObject();
    }
}
```